# React - Which way is better to pass arguments to prop functions in an array of stateless components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm refactorying my react components, and wondering which way to pass arguments to prop functions is cleaner and more readable between a parent component and an array of children components.

1. pass arguments in the child component

```js
const ChildComponent = ({data, onButtonClick}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.name}
      <button type="button" onClick={() => onButtonClick(data.id)}>Clcik</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const list = [{id: 'a', name: 'Apple'}, {id: 'b', name: 'Banana'}];
  const recordId = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
  };
  return (
    list.map((item) => (
      <ChildComponent key={item.id} data={item} onButtonClick={recordId} />
    ))
  );
};
```

2. pass arguments in the parent component

```
const ChildComponent2 = ({data, onButtonClick}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.name}
      <button type="button" onClick={onButtonClick}>Clcik</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const ParentComponent2 = () => {
  const list = [{id: 'a', name: 'Apple'}, {id: 'b', name: 'Banana'}];
  const recordId = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
  };
  return (
    list.map((item) => (
      <ChildComponent2 key={item.id} data={item} onButtonClick={() => recordId(item.id)} />
    ))
  );
};
```

Comment: If it's just the `id` you can set the id of the element and not pass any arguments but retrieve it from the implicitly passed `event` parameter. But otherwise, it seems better to pass the function to the child and then allow the child to pass arguments as the end user of the function (if you're passing control to the child it implies that the child should have agency over the use of the passed function, ie tracking any changes to what may be passed)

Comment: In my application, a list item is a big object including detailed data, and the prop function is to control other components that related to the target (like an image popup, a modal, or a message, ...etc)

Comment: Approach one is more readable and cleaner, and I also did this way. 2nd one could be little confusing as you pass argument in parent component.

Comment: @pilchard I don't think that pushing data not related to DOM (like `id` here) into the DOM is a good idea. Let data concerned with the app logic stay in React land and not leak it into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is better from optimization perspective because you can easily convert `recordId` into a stable entity (either by moving it outside of a component body since it's a pure function or using `useCallback`) so it won't trigger unnecessary rendering of the children (if you decide to use `React.memo` on them).

The second way is better from teamwork perspective. If another person takes care of `ChildComponent` he/she doesn't need to know anything about `onClick` handler coming from the parent because it's already assembled so all is there to do is to pass it on the button.